# Swift Macro #unwrap

Tags: swift, wwdc

In Apple's [WWDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Worldwide_Developers_Conference) 2023 they announced macros and, among others, they showed us this code snippet:

```
macro unwrap<Wrapped>(_ expr: Wrapped, message: String) -> Wrapped
```

I have downloaded Xcode 15 Beta and tried to get it to work, without result. I get the error message of:

> Macro 'unwrap(_:message:)' requires a definition

What can I do or how can I write this correctly?

Comment: Could you include a sample showing how you try to use it?

Comment: What is the weird underscore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new macro.In Xcode File → New → Package... and select Swift Macro

Comment: Hey and welcome, i noticed that after a while. Thank you for your answer though. Now i have finally built a lot of cool macros :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found your code snippet, but instead take a look at the video of WWDC, *[Write Swift macros](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10166)*, 06:36.

When creating a macro you need to declare the definition of your macro... For example in the video...

We have the macro

```
let (result, code) = #stringify(a+b)
```

To dive into the definition of `#stringify`...

```
// A macro that produces both a value and a string containing
// the source code that generated the value

@freestanding(expression)
public macro stringify<T>(_ value: T) -> (T, String) = #externalMacro(module: "WWDCMacros", type: "StringifyMacro")
```

So I guess that you are just missing the correct implementation. Do you have a implementation file of your macro?

Does it have the correct initializer?

```
// Check the overview here:
@freestanding(expression) // Creates a piece of code that returns a value
@freestanding(declaration) // Creates one or more declarations
@attached(peer) // Adds new declarations alongside the declaration its applied to
@attached(accessor) // Adds accessors to a property
@attached(memberAttribute) // Adds new declarations inside the type/extension its applied to
@attached(member) // Adds new declarations inside the type/extension its applied to
@attached(conformance) // Adds conformances to the type/extension its applied to
```